# Access SQL for multiple LEFT JOIN cant work

Tags: ms-access, left-join

TableA

| Shop ID | Item | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shop A | Item1 | 101 |
| Shop A | Item2 | 102 |
| Shop A | Item3 | 103 |
| Shop A | Item4 | 104 |
| Shop A | Item5 | 105 |
| Shop A | Item6 | 106 |
| Shop A | Item7 | 107 |
| ...... | ..... | ..... |
| Shop A | Item27 | 127 |
| Shop B | Item1 | 201 |
| Shop B | ..... | ..... |
| Shop B | Item27 | 227 |
| Shop C | Item1 | 301 |
| Shop C | ..... | ..... |
| Shop C | Item27 | 327 |

Suppose I have a table like above in which I would like to convert to table below

| Shop ID | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | ..... | Item27 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shop A | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | ..... | 127 |

I tried using query with multiple left joins

```
SELECT T1.[Shop ID], T1.[Price] AS Item1 .... T27.[Price] AS Item 27

FROM (TableA AS T1
LEFT JOIN TableA AS T2 ON T1.[Shop ID] = T2.[Shop ID])
LEFT JOIN TableA AS T3 ON T1.[Shop ID] = T3.[Shop ID])
...
LEFT JOIN TableA AS T27 ON T1.[Shop ID] = T27.[Shop ID]

WHERE T1.[Item] = 'Item1'
AND T2.[Item] = 'Item2'
...
AND T27.[Item] = 'Item27'
AND T1.[Shop ID] = 'Shop A'
```

This work for smaller number of LEFT JOIN but when number of LEFT JOIN > 20, Access essentially stopped forever, my actual table is a bit more complicate. Any one can suggest ways for the conversion? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use a pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    [Shop ID],
    MAX(IIF([Item] = "Item1", Price, NULL)) AS Item1,
    MAX(IIF([Item] = "Item2", Price, NULL)) AS Item2,
    MAX(IIF([Item] = "Item3", Price, NULL)) AS Item3,
    ...
    MAX(IIF([Item] = "Item27", Price, NULL)) AS Item27
FROM TableA
GROUP BY [Shop ID]
ORDER BY [Shop ID];
```

You may also look into cross tab options with MS Access.

Comment: What if my TableA have an column "Open Date of the shop" and I would like to sort the column by date column, there is an error, ```Your query dose not include the specific expression 'Date' as part of the aggregate function'```

Comment: Add the `Date` column to the `SELECT` clause as well, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I added ```Date``` in the ```SELECT``` and it wont work, but it work when I add ```Date``` into ```GROUP BY```.

Answer (score 0):

Try CrossTab query like-

```
TRANSFORM First(t.Price) AS FirstOfPrice
SELECT t.ShopID
FROM TableA as t
GROUP BY t.ShopID
ORDER BY t.Item
PIVOT t.Item;
```

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Can I change the column name from Item x to other name like removing the letter ‘Item’ from the column name